# How much current does a component draw

Tags: arduino, current, sensor

I have a hc sr04 sensor and looking at the datasheet it says its working current is 15mA and voltage is 5v. If i hook it up to the 5v rail will it draw 15mA without the need for a resistor? How does it know to just draw 15mA without getting damaged?

Comment: How do you know it hasn't got a resistor inside? ;)

Comment: It's the same as asking "How does a 10 liter bucket know it can't contain 11 liters of water".

Comment: *How does it know to just draw 15mA without getting damaged?* It doesn't "know", it is simply the results of the design. I can design a circuit which draws 15 mA **without using any resistors** and even without using any ICs which could have resistors inside (there are already 3 ICs on that sr04 module). Maybe you should not make assumptions on how things work before you gained some more knowledge about electronics ?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate, but I can't find the previous question. Does anyone remember this question, I think within the last four weeks? I also believe a question was closed recently because the person showed such a poor grasp of electronic basics; that seems a bit harsh, but this sort of question is answered in lots of school level tutorials. I don't think we need more than one answer to this sort of thing.

Comment: I find this surprisingly difficult to answer. 'Measure the current and see what it draws' is both a complete answer, and none at all.

Comment: @Neil_UK - I think a reasonable answer is very close to your comment: "assume someone connected it up, measured the current to see what it draws, and wrote that down on a datasheet". Further, the datsheet would explicitly say that it needs to be wired up with a resistor if it can't be connected to 5V directly. This isn't even physics, it's just how manufacturers describe their products so that they are usable.

Comment: I don't see any difficulty in saying/understanding the description "If you put an object *O* under conditions *C*, it will have a behavior *B*". In this case `O=hc-sr04`, `C=<input voltage of 5V>` and `B=<draws current of 15mA>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a component - it is a whole device (the back side). It is designed with these parameters and it definitely has a "resistor" inside:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't 'know' as you speak. It works like many components, and it draws current based on Ohm's law: \$I= \frac{V}{R}\$. If the Voltage is 5 Volts, and the current is .015 Amperes, then the resistance is \$R= \frac{5}{.015} = 333Ohms\$. This resistance is adjusted as certain transistors let current through, and components activate, and whatnot, but the device itself won't 'decide' what its resistance is supposed to be.

Comment: Well, you are making an assumption the module is a purely resitive load. I bet it is not.

Comment: @EugeneSh. this is true, however for the sake of simplicity, it does the job

Answer (score 1):

The component doesn't "know it needs 15mA". It takes whatever it needs to operate, no more, no less. To use the cliche water analogy, suppose you have a large water cooler at work. You go up to it and start drinking from it. How do you know how much to drink? You take however much water you need. The power supply is just a reservoir, and the components take from it what they need to operate. The only problem would be if the reservoir doesn't have enough to supply all of the components pulling from it (i.e. the water cooler runs out of water before you're done drinking from it).